run github file in databricks community edition
I'm trying to run a databricks notebook.
From what I understand, I should link my github account with databrick, but it can't be done with community edition.
Therefore, I tried input the following in two different cells, but it won't work.
%sh git clone https://github.com/databricks-academy/large-language-models
%run ./large-large-language-models/Includes/Classroom-Setup


Notebook not found: databricks/driver/large-large-language-models/Includes/Classroom-Setup. Notebooks can be specified via a relative path (./Notebook
or ../folder/Notebook) or via an absolute path
(/Abs/Path/to/Notebook). Make sure you are specifying the path correctly.


-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 938 Apr  3 11:44 /databricks/driver/large-language-models/Includes/Classroom-Setup.py

(I tried 20ish variations of the run path, but non worked)
Any idea how to solve this ?
Thx

did you try without repeating "large" in the run command?
